# know the type of the response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, response

I want know the type of the response of an action controller (json, html, xml)
before the instructions:

```
respond_to do |format|
        format.html{
...
end
```

Is possible?

Thanks

Comment: is `request.format` acceptable for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use,

```
request.format.symbol
```

this will list down the current request format.

If you want any thing else in detailed, I suggest to inspect the request object,

```
p request.inpect
```

Comment: If an xhr request is made, the symbol may be nil. You can check if the request is xhr with `request.xhr?`